# webpack 4.5 set proxy company

Tags: webpack, proxy

Can I set my company proxy in Webpack 4.5 with react?

I use my localhost for my FE and I call WS in other external IP, I can ping it from terminal but webpack resolve it with `ECONNREFUSED`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: This looks more like a network/system administration question...

Comment: // , Stefano, interesting question. I bet other people are wondering the same thing. Can you show the actual code and output that you used? Also, what research have you done on this already?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your companies proxy server is configured, you may be able to use the `proxy` option in webpack-dev-server.  See the docs here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy

Something along this lines of:

```
proxy: {
  "/api": {
    target: "http://your companiesproxyserver:3000",
    pathRewrite: {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used this configuration to make a reverse proxy to call BE WS from my localhost, but my coorporate proxy resolve it with ECONNREFUSED.